# True or False: If $f>0$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then $f^p$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

when  $p=1,-1,1/2$ and some real number, I could prove it with the Riemann integration definition.

Could someone give me some stronger conclusion?

when $p$ is a rational number i could use the condition that $\displaystyle f$ is bounded and the set of discontinuous points measures $0$.
can it apply to the irrational number $p$?

Comment: @Serios I think $f^{\frac12}$ is integrable ...

Comment: @Serios we can use a little segment to control the $f\delta<M$ because you had define $f(0)=1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lebesgue theorem, a *bounded* function $f$ on a segment is  a Riemann integrable iff the set of the discontinuity points of $f$ has the Lebesgue measure $0$. So It seems that you claim should be true, provided one of the following conditions hold:

– $0\le p\le 1$;

– $p<0$ and $f$ is separated from the zero, that is $\inf f>0$;

– $p>1$ and $f$ is bounded, that is $\sup f<\infty$.

Comment: Must a Riemann integrable function $f$ be bounded?

Comment: If you consider a proper integral, as the limit of the integral summs, if seems so. But a boundness is not necessary for the non-proper integrlas.

Comment: sorry can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: As I remember, if the function is unbounded, there should not exist a finite limit of it’s [Riemann sum](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Riemann_integral).
So, if we wish to consider the integrals of unbounded functions, then we should use tricks. For instance, if $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and is unbounded at the point $b$, but for each $a<c<b$ the function $f$ is bounded and integrable on $[a,c]$ and there exists a limit $I=\lim_{c\to b} \int_a^c f(x) dx$, we may consider $I$ as an (non-proper) value of the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$.